# Массив из булевых переменных

Tags: c++, массивы

Я хочу сделать так, что бы некоторый набор элементов в массиве при запуске имел значение true. В дальнейшем, когда пользователь занимает какую либо ячейку её значение менялось на false.
Пример, я объявляю массив типа bool с 3мя элементами, которые на момент запуска имеют значение true. В дальнейшем пользователю предлагается вводить числа. Если пользователь вводит 0, а затем ещё раз 0, то ему выдаётся предупреждение.

Код:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool myArray[3] = {true};
    int action;
    bool TurnOff = false;

    do
    {
        cout << "Action: ";
        cin >> action;

            if (myArray[action] ==  true)
            {
                cout << "This cell is free\n";
                myArray[action] = false;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "this cell is busy\n";
            }
    }
    while (TurnOff != true);
    cout << "Done";
}
```

Теоретически, я рассчитывал, что если в первый раз пользователь введёт 0, будет выводиться сообщение, что ячейка свободна, и отдельное сообщение, если она уже занята. Суть проблемы в том, что если ввести 0, затем ещё раз 0, то всё работает как положено. Если ввести 1, то программа сразу скажет, что такая ячейка уже занята. Пример выхода программы:

```
Action: 0
This cell is free
Action: 1
this cell is busy
Action: 2
this cell is busy
Action: 4
This cell is free
Action: 5
This cell is free
Action: 6
This cell is free
Action: 7
this cell is busy
Action: 8
This cell is free
Action: 9
This cell is free
Action: 0
this cell is busy
Action: 11
this cell is busy
Action: 12
This cell is free
Action:
```

Почему программа допускает использования чисел больше, чем 2? Ведь я указал размер массива равным 3.

Я осознаю, что совершенно не понимаю как работают булевые массивы. Как сделать так, что бы большому количеству элементов массива при запуске было присвоено значение True (доступна) и менялась на False только если она уже использовалась?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*"Я осознаю, что совершенно не понимаю как работают булевые массивы."* - точно так же, как и любого другого типа.

Вот это

```
bool myArray[3] = {true};
```

определяет массив из трех элементов, в котором первый (с индексом 0) элемент имеет значение `true`, остальные - `false`. Все, что далее - нетронутая память. К которой вы не имеете права обращаться, но ответственность за проверку выхода за границы массива лежит только на вас.

Так что если хотите инициализировать массив так, как хотите :) - то

```
bool myArray[3] = {true,true,true};
```

Ну, или используйте, скажем,

```
vector<bool> myArray(3, true);
```

И - проверяйте обязательно выход за пределы массива - понятно, что если вы введете `action` больше 2 (или меньше 0) - то получите UB.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы попробуете вывести на экран ваш массив, то увидите `true, false, false`. Если в списке инициализации меньше значений чем в массиве, то последние ячейки массива будут инициализироваться нулями.

Для того чтобы заполнить весь массив каким-то значением используйте [`std::fill_n`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/fill_n/?kw=fill_n);

```
#include <algorithm>
//...

std::fill_n(myArray, 3, true);
```

Что каcается выхода за пределы массива, то это исключительно на вашей совести. Выход за границы массива ведет к неопределенному поведению. Неопределенным поведением может быть все что угодно: нормальная работа, сегфолт, форматирование жесткого диска. Вам, похоже, на этот раз повезло :)